# Does the Vietnam Phu Quoc National Park allow visitors to camp on the grounds?

Tags: camping, vietnam, national-parks

We (group of two) want to travel to Phu Quoc Island, arriving at Bai Thom (north), rent some mountain bikes and travel through the National Park to the south of the island.

Is there a possibility to sleep outside (anywhere we like, I assume highly unlikely acorrding to [this link](https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g469418-i10303-k8014519-Can_you_camp_on_Phu_Quoc-Phu_Quoc_Island_Kien_Giang_Province.html)) or on a camping place? We would like to sleep outside, but of course not break any laws.

We are aware that protection against mosquitos is required.

Comment: Relevant: https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g469418-i10303-k8014519-Can_you_camp_on_Phu_Quoc-Phu_Quoc_Island_Kien_Giang_Province.html and https://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/forums/asia-south-east-asia-mainland/vietnam/reality-check-camping and https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g293921-i8432-k6539301-Camping_in_Vietnam-Vietnam.html

Comment: When I went (**December 2018**) even the access was restricted to tourists, I wanted to walk through, side to side, without camping but I wasn't allowed to.

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't actually go into the park. There is a condensed populations of dangerous wild animals as well as poachers that will protect their areas. There is no cell service and it's too dangerous for even the locals.

The tours and guides you see online all take you outside of the actual park in safe areas. We talked to our guide while visiting about going into the park and he laughed telling us how unrealistic that was. It's not at all like displayed on the net - still beautiful and worth visiting but, you can't go into the park.  Nor would you want to.

Answer (score 2):

To the best of my knowledge, there is no organized camping inside the National Park.